Downloading File Notification via Browser
I have a large chunk of data which I am downloading to a file via a JS web app. Normally whenever I download a file on a different website, my browser (chrome) shows some sort of download progress , either at bottom of window or in top menu bar. I can't seem to do this, it just downloads the file and that's it. I could of course do my own progress update, but I am curious why it is not happening. I thought maybe the browser would detect that a download is in place, but is there some specific code I need to add?
